# AZURE HD INSIGHT (Cluster) Import CSV file to storage: Creating a table

Tags: azure, bigdata, apache-zeppelin, azure-hdinsight

I am absolutely new to coding - I know the basics so I'm pulling my hair out here on this project.

I am attempting to link my Hadoop cluster to Tableau in the end, where the bulk of my project will be focused on.
I am following [this guy](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Data-Analysis-with-Tableau-and-Spark-on-Azure-HDInsight?term=tableau%20HD%20INSIGHT&lang-en=true).

However, he does not explain exactly how to link the CSV file to cluster. After a little research, I find that I need to import the data via a cluster.
I have managed to import the CSV File via CloudXplorer. Now I just need to create the tables.

I am getting no luck through Ambari (create a table the error is error fetching databases and it never really uploaded my file at the beginning anyway) OR on Zeppelin.

My code on Zeppelin follows:

```html
%livy2.spark
 //The above magic instructs Zeppelin to use the Livy Scala interpreter

 // Create an RDD using the default Spark context, sc
 val SearchText = sc.textFile("wasb://test'myname'1@.blob.core.windows.net/sample/stopandsearch.csv")

 // Define a schema
 case class Search(Type: String, date: String, time: String, LATITUDE: String, LONGITUDE: String, Gender: String, Age_Range: String, Self_defined_Eth: String, Officer_defined_Eth: String, Legislation: String, Obj_Of_Search: String, Outcome: String)

 // Map the values in the .csv file to the schema
 val Search = SearchText.map(s => s.split(",")).map(
     s => Search(s(6), 
             s(1),
             s(7),
             s(3),
             s(6),
             s(7),
             s(3),
             s(7),
             s(12),
             s(12),
             s(12)
     )
 ).toDF()
 Search.registerAsTable("Search")
 Search.saveAsTable("Search")
<console>:30: error: recursive value Search needs type
            s => Search(s(6),
                 ^
<console>:42: error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
        ).toDF()
          ^
```

any suggestions, please. Any shortcut around this, I just need to insert the data into nice tables! :)

Thanks  in advance.

PS I have no idea how to get the link to wasb? THE Http [link](https://test'myname'1.blob.core.windows.net/sample/stopandsearch.csv) for the csv file in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think this path is not correct .

```
wasb://test'myname'1@.blob.core.windows.net/sample/stopandsearch.csv"
```

it should be

```
wasb://test'myname'1@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/sample/stopandsearch.csv"
```

You are missing the storageaccount and I am assuming that test'myname'1 is the container name .